# How can assign values to rows with unique values?

Tags: r

For example I have:

```
df[1,] <- c('a','b','c')
df[2,] <- c('h','a','f')
df[3,] <- c('d','e','g')
df[4,] <- c('h','a','g')
```

Lets say I want to create a new column that groups the data by uniqueness for the first 2 values in each row for the first 2 columns. So the final result would look like:

```
df[1,] <- c('a','b','c',1)
df[2,] <- c('h','a','f',2)
df[3,] <- c('d','e','g',3)
df[4,] <- c('h','a','g',2)
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: i don't understand the rule for the last column.

Comment: For instance, 'a' & 'b' is one group so it is assigned 1. 'h','a' is another unique group so it is assigned 2, for row 4, 'h','a' has already been seen in row 2, so I want the last column to also have a value of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(unique_combination = group_indices(group_by(df, col_1, col_2)))
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  col_1 col_2 col_3 unique_combination
  <chr> <chr> <chr>              <int>
1 a     b     c                      1
2 h     a     f                      3
3 d     e     g                      2
4 h     a     g                      3
```

```
# Data used:
df <- structure(list(col_1 = c("a", "h", "d", "h"), col_2 = c("b", "a", "e", "a"), col_3 = c("c", "f", "g", "g")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in plain R:

```
df <- data.frame("c1"=character(0), "c2"=character(0), "c3"=character(0))
df[1,] <- c('a','b','c')
df[2,] <- c('h','a','f')
df[3,] <- c('d','e','g')
df[4,] <- c('h','a','g')

df$c4 <- as.integer(factor(paste0(df$c1, df$c2)))
```

The idea is to concatenate the content of the first two columns, convert it as factor and then to use only the integer representation of the factor.